# Javascript - detect OS and redirect to mobile app installed

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, mobile-application, browser-detection

On a webpage, I want to redirect the user to an app if it is installed on their phone and if not, to a different URL.  For example:

- phone: Windows, url: app://url1
- phone: iPhone, url: app://url2, redirectURL: https://itunes.apple.com/app/123456
- phone: Android, url: app://url3, redirectURL: https://www.google.com

I've attached my code below.  It works as expected for the Windows phone.  However for the iPhone, if the app isn't installed, a message pops up "Safari can not open the page." before being redirected to the redirectURL.  Is there any way to avoid this or a better method to implement this?

My code so far:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myHref() {

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone [1-8]/i)) {
            location.href = 'app://url1';
        }

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))) {

            document.location = 'app://url2';
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (confirm('You do not seem to have the app installed. Do you want to go download it now?')) {
                    location.href = 'https://itunes.apple.com/app/123456';
                }
            }, 300);

        }

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
            location.href = "app://url3"
        }

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)) {
            //code for blackberry here
        }

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)) {
            //code for webOS here 
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <a href="#" onclick="myHref()" style="font-size:20px;">link</a>
</p>
</body>
```